# Android, event listener?

Tags: android

I have a loop that runs through an array of image views, adding an event listener to each, how can I find out which image view was pressed inside the listener?

```
imageViewArray[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(View v) {

                   }        
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set id for each on the index value like eg: image_view.setId(i);

Comment: how do I get the id in the event listener?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the `v` parameter to the `onClick` method provide a reference to the `ImageView`?

**EDIT**
The thing is: You are not adding the same listener to all of the `ImageView`s in your code - every `ImageView` in your array gets its own listener.

In the listener's `onClick` method, the `View` that raised the event is passed in `v`, so when working with `v` you're working with the clicked `ImageView`.

To find the *index of the `ImageView`* in your array, you might as well set the ID as suggested by others and then use `v.getId()`, or you could loop over your array and check whether `imageViewArray[i] == v`, in which case `i` is the index of your `ImageView` within the array.

Answer (score 0):

`imageView.getId()` will return you the ID you give this `ImageView` in `findViewById()` 
method. Then you can check the ID's in a switch block. Hope this helps.